# After upgrading to High Sierra NTFS format mobile HDD fails to load

Tags: hard-drive, windows, usb, high-sierra, ntfs

I encountered a problem after upgrading to High Sierra. I have a mobile hard drive which is NTFS formatted (USB 3.0).

When I connect my hard drive to the computer, it **doesn't appear in Finder. It can be found in the Disk Utility but it is grayed out**. Mobile hard disk is working properly because in other windows computer connection is fine, before the upgrade (macOS 10.12) can also be displayed in finder.

Hardware: MacBook Pro 13 2017 16 GB RAM & 256 GB SSD without Touch Bar.

Comment: Were you able to read and write to the NTFS disk from macOS before the High Sierra upgrade?

Comment: Yes. The Mac comes with the system is 10.12, It can read NTFS default and write after install paragon NTFS 15. There was a problem after upgrading 10.13. Then I downgrade to 10.12 and can be used. It can not be used after the upgrade again, both read and write.

Answer (score 1):

I also have similar problem, but luckily, it can read the drives. Perhaps your drive was not mounted. Now I temporarily use virtual Windows through VirtualBox to write to the drives while waiting for a complete solution.

My machine is iMac late 2015.